# Sudo unable to resolve host name (none)

Tags: sudo

Any command I put into the LXTerminal of my raspberry pi, it says Sudo unable to resolve host (none)
 I can’t download anything, even Sudo apt-get update 
How do I fix this"?

Comment: This is indicative of an attempt to manually change hostname. You need to specify what you have done.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `nano /etc/hostname`

There you should find one line with the name of your machine.

Then have a look at `nano /etc/hosts`
There you should find two lines. One localhost and one with your hostname:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       your_host_name
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem manifests itself when a command is issued under `sudo`. For example:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
sudo: unable to resolve host the_name: Name or service not known
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

In other words, the command executes as it should, but the annoying error message appears after each use of `sudo`:

> **sudo: unable to resolve host <XXXX>: Name or service not known**

I don't know what causes this issue, but here's something that may fix it:

1. get your hostname from /etc/hostname, or:

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
the_name
# --OR--
$ hostname
the_name
```

2. check your `/etc/hosts` file; you may see something like this:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.1.1   raspberrypi
::1         localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
```

3. There should be two entries for the *loopback* address (127.0.0.1). The problem is caused when one of the *loopback* addresses does not have the proper hostname assigned, or has no name assigned, or there is only one line for this address.

Remedy this by opening the `/etc/hosts` file in your editor, and changing the hostname for second entry/line 127.0.0.1 to the same name that is in the `/etc/hostname` file. Using this case as an example, change the second line:

#### FROM:

127.0.1.1   raspberrypi

#### TO:

127.0.1.1   the_name

You can double-check this after your edit - you should see this:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.1.1   the_name
::1         localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
```

And that should take care of it.